# unable to update the array using pull in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I wanted to delete 'user' entry from 'roleAssigned' array
In the code:

```
Contact.update({ firstName:'Abhishek'},{$pull: { roleAssigned:'user'}});
```

This is what the Contact mongoDB model looks like:

```
[{
    roleAssigned: ['user', 'admin'],
    _id: 5b9b8ef904bc042c8f94f1fe,
    firstName: 'abhishek',
    lastName: 'soni',
    date: 2018-09-14T10:35:37.922Z,
    __v: 0
}]
```

Comment: can you post the schema please?

Comment: export const contactschema = new schema({
    firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: 'enter your first name '
    },
    lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: 'enter your last name '
    },
    roleAssigned: {
     type: Array,
     default: []
     },
     email: {
     type: String
     }})

Comment: `"Abhishek"` and `"abhishek"` both are different. Either use small `a` or use `$regex` in your above query. Something like this **`Contact.update({ firstName:{ $regex: 'Abhishek', $options: "i" }},{ $pull: { roleAssigned: 'user' }})`**

Comment: i did the change but I am getting this error msg
errmsg: 'Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value'

Comment: I ran same query with the same document and it worked for me. You might doing something wrong.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet yeah thanks it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution to solve your problem:

```
{ $pullAll: { roleAssigned: ['user'] } };
```